# Extra + in output when looping; javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

My desired output is: 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 45

The output I'm getting is: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 +  = 15 (with an extra + side on the end). I'm not sure how to get it to output without the extra + at the end, and am clearly not searching for the right terms to figure it out. Thanks!

Here's my code:
function exercise7Part2() {
    // PART 2: YOUR CODE STARTS AFTER THIS LINE

```
// Declare variables
var loopStart;
var loopMax;
var total;

// Assignments
loopStart = Number(prompt("Enter a number:"));
loopMax = Number(prompt("Enter a number larger than the last:")); 

total = 0;

// Processing
while (loopStart <= loopMax)
{
    total += loopStart;
    document.write(loopStart + " + ");
    loopStart++;   
}
document.write(" = " + total);
```

}

Comment: don;t add the plus on the last index. Or start with a value and than do "+" with the next value.

Comment: `document.write(loopStart+ (loopStart!=loopMax ? "+" : ""));` this will do the job. You must check if loopStart and loopMax aren't equal to print the `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're printing `loopState + "+"` which will always print the `+` at the end. Instead you must check if it's the last value and prevent the `+` from printing or else, use a ternary operator to print it.

In this example, I'm checking if both loopStart and loopMax are not equal. if they're not equal then am appending `+` at the end.

It will be like:

```
    document.write(loopStart+ (loopStart!=loopMax ? "+" : ""));
```

Here `(loopStart!=loopMax ? "+" : "")` is a ternary operator. The `loopStart!=loopMax` is an boolean expression. It's evaluated and if it's true the first parameter after `?` will be used so in this case `+` and if its false anythign after `:` will be used so in this case its `""` empty string.

```js
// Declare variables
var loopStart;
var loopMax;
var total;

// Assignments
loopStart = Number(prompt("Enter a number:"));
loopMax = Number(prompt("Enter a number larger than the last:")); 

total = 0;

// Processing
while (loopStart <= loopMax)
{
    total += loopStart;
    document.write(loopStart+ (loopStart!=loopMax ? "+" : ""));
    loopStart++;   
}
document.write(" = " + total);
```

With normal `if` condition block

```
while (loopStart <= loopMax)
{
    total += loopStart;
    if(loopStart===loopMax) {
       document.write(loopStart);
    } else {
       document.write(loopStart+ "+");
    }
    loopStart++;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In this --> (loopStart != loopMax ? " + " : "")  -- what are the ? and ":" doing, exactly?

Comment: Updated in answer :) In short, it's similar to `if` condition. if the condition `(loopStart != loopMax)` is true then evaluate `+` else print `""` empty string

Comment: @jdogmcgee: Instead of `... ? ... : ...` you can also just use a normal `if` to check if you are at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Declare variables
var loopStart;
var loopMax;
var total;

// Assignments
loopStart = Number(prompt("Enter a number:"));
loopMax = Number(prompt("Enter a number larger than the last:")); 

total = 0;

// Processing
while (loopStart <= loopMax)
{
    total += loopStart;
    document.write(loopStart+ (loopStart!=loopMax ? "+" : ""));
    loopStart++;   
}
document.write(" = " + total);
```

Comment: You're copy pasting my own answer :P instead you can just accept mine as correct answer :)